# Which login manager am I using?

Tags: debian, xfce, login-manager

I have Debian installed, and am using XFCE. How do I figure out which login manager I have installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This command should list all of your Login managers installed:

```
dpkg -l | grep -i 'Display Manager\|Login Manager' | awk '$2 !~ /^lib/'
```

It will search for the keywords "Display Manager" and "Login Manager" and show only things that do not start with "lib" on the second column.

**Note**: If you have more than one Display Manager configured, it will show both. You will have to use `dpkg-reconfigure kdm` for example to turn that login manager as your default.